# A Simple Seasonal Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme, seasonal

The first line of this riddle has been stuck in my head for some time, so I figured I'd write it down. The rest I came up with recently.

> Sleeping soldiers symbolize my start,
>
> while worker's feats shall bring about my end.
>
> If you have a job, I might mean little,
>
> but if you are in school, I am your friend.
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like

> Summer or Summer Vacation

Sleeping soldiers symbolize my start,

> Memorial Day in the U.S. begins the summer (unofficially)

while worker's feats shall bring about my end.

> Labor Day in the U.S. ends the summer (unofficially)

If you have a job, I might mean little,

> Trudge off to work in the summer, same as all other seasons

but if you are in school, I am your friend.

> Off of school for the summer!

And the title

> summer is a season

Comment: Your first answer was correct; the season, not the vacation. I wish i could've made the second line an alliteration, but I got lazy looking for synonyms and couldn't think of any.

Comment: Also, I knew it would be easy, but it would bother me if I didn't write it down eventually.